# Implementing java 8 DriverAction Interface

Tags: java, jdbc

I am running simple JDBC demo program where I used DriverAction interface and its deregister method to test its functionality, but I received error for my Dirver class, please find below code and suggest what is missing.

//error -com.mysql can not be resolve to type error

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Jdbcexample implements DriverAction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        Driver driver = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();/*com.mysql can not be resolve to type error */
        DriverAction driveraction = new Jdbcexample();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver,driveraction);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
        Statement stmt =con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs =stmt.executeQuery("select* from user");
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+""+rs.getString(2)+""+rs.getString(3));
        }
        con.close();
    DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

}

    @Override
    public void deregister() {
        System.out.println("Driver is deregistered");

    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the error you got? ([edit] your question and add the error message)

Comment: If the error is the one mentioned in the comment ("com.mysql can not be resolved to type"), make sure the MySQL JDBC driver JAR is in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself means that you don't have a driver on the classpath when you're compiling your code. However the bigger problem is that you should not be doing this.

The `DriverManager.registerDriver` methods are **not** for user programs to call. They are for JDBC drivers to register themselves. The `DriverManager.registerDriver(Driver, DriverAction)` is a callback mechanism for the driver to do additional work when it is deregistered.

From the javadoc:

> Registers the given driver with the `DriverManager`. A newly-loaded
>   driver class should call the method `registerDriver` to make itself
>   known to the `DriverManager`. If the driver is currently registered,
>   no action is taken.

The important part is *"A newly-loaded driver class should call the method registerDriver to make **itself** known to the DriverManager."*.

And on `DriverAction`:

> An interface that must be implemented when a `Driver` wants to be
>   notified by `DriverManager`.

So, it is for JDBC drivers themselves, not for user programs.